# passport google : why sessionID is different in the callback?

Tags: node.js, session, passport-google-oauth2

Dears,

there are a lot of examples around passport google, but there should be something I missed. I know my question might be marked as "possible duplicate", but sorry I can't find the answer, or none of them are fixing my issue.

the user clicks a href link on the client (running on https://localhost:3000), calling the googleauth route on the server (running on https://localhost).

On server side, passport process is running well, the callbackUrl is on the server side at /googleauth/redirect.

Then in this callback, I can hardcoded the redirect to 'https://localhost:3000'. that works fine.

But I don't want this. I want the server to catch the initial url from the client (so https://localhost:3000), keep it in the session and then use this information in the redirect.

In the google auth route, I set the toRedirect variable into the session thanks a middleware, before calling the passport.authenticate.

```
googleRouter.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.toRedirect) req.session.toRedirect = req.socket.remoteAddress;
    next();
}, Auth.passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email', 'https://mail.google.com/'],
    accessType: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent',
    session: false   // <-- whatever true or false, same issue
})
);
```

However once the google process is complete (choose the google account and confirm the acces to user data),  the sessionID is different in the callback, therefore the url to redirect is undefined... And of course the remote address is no longer the client one, but the google authentification APIs one...

```
googleRouter.get('/redirect', Auth.passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.toRedirect, req.sessionID, req.socket.remoteAddress)  // <--- sessionID is different so req.session.toRedirect is undefined

    res.redirect('https://localhost:3000'); /<--- hardocded here but I want res.redirect(req.session.toRedirect).
});
```

So guys, how did you send back the google auth results to your clients ?

Here is the code

**apps.js**

```
const passport = Auth.passport;
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); <-- whatever set or not, same issue
```

**auth.js**

```
const googleOptions = {
    clientID: sds,
    clientSecret: dsadd,
    callbackURL: '/googleauth/redirect',
    passReqToCallback: true
};
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(googleOptions,
    async (req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            data = await Auth.helpers.signIn(req, null, 'google');
            if (data && data.erreur == authErrors.NONE) {
                //  MAJ de la session et cookie
                req.session.userId = data.user.id;
                done(null, data.user);
            };
));
```

**googleroutes**

```
googleRouter.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.toRedirect) req.session.toRedirect = req.socket.remoteAddress;
    next();
}, Auth.passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email', 'https://mail.google.com/'],
    accessType: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent',
    session: false
})
);

// callback route pour redirect google
googleRouter.get('/redirect', Auth.passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.toRedirect, req.sessionID, req.socket.remoteAddress)
    res.redirect('https://localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: have you managed to deal with this problem?

Comment: not really. I have added in the URL from the client a parameter set to the url to be redirected. Then in the server, this parameter  is saved at app level `app.set('toredir',req.params.toredir')`. then once google process is complete and user is confirmed in the database, manage the redirect by calling `app.redirect(app.get('toredir')`. I find this solution not clean at all, but the only one I can make work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by saving the redirect URL into a cookie using [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser). Here's what your code might look like using that method:

**googleroutes**

```
googleRouter.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.cookie('toRedirect', req.socket.remoteAddress, {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15 // 15 minutes
    });
    next();
}, Auth.passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email', 'https://mail.google.com/'],
    accessType: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent',
    session: false
})
);

// callback route pour redirect google
googleRouter.get('/redirect', Auth.passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    const redirectUrl = req.cookies.toRedirect ? req.cookies.toRedirect : '/';

    res.cookie('toRedirect', '', {
        maxAge: 0
    }); // Reset cookie

    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
});
```